# Vuex Store Module access state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to know how to access module store/state from another file.
This is my code so far:

/store/index.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import categories from './modules/categories';

Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  actions: {

  },
  mutations: {

  },
  getters: {

  },
  modules: {
    categories,
  },
});
export default store;
```

/store/modules/categories.js

```
const categories = {
  state: {
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'category1'
        path: 'path/to/there'
        subcategories: [
          {
            name: 'subcategory1'
            path: 'path/to/other/there'
            subsubcategory: [
              {
                name: 'subsubcategory1'
                path: 'path/to/other/there'
              }
              {
                name: 'subsubcategory1'
                path: 'path/to/other/there'
              }
            ]
          }
          {
            name: 'subcategory2'
            path: 'path/to/other/there'
          }
        ]
      }
      {
        name: 'category2'
        path: 'path/to/there'
        subcategories: [
          {
            name: 'subcategory2'
            path: 'path/to/other/there'
          }
          {
            name: 'subcategory3'
            path: 'path/to/other/there'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  actions: {

  },
  mutations: {

  },
  getters: {

  },
}
```

edit: I want to be able to access modules state/store here for example:
/home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Headers></Headers>
    <div class="user row">
      <p>User Page</p>
      <p> I want to be able to access modules store/state here and be able to pass getters here to filter some results from state</p>
    </div>
    <Footers></Footers>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import 'vue-awesome/icons';
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import Headers from '/Headers';
import Footers from '/Footers';

export default {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  components: {
    Headers,
    Footers,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      '',
    ]),
    ...mapState([
      'categories',
    ]),
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Now, I was able to access and loop through categories before, but thnx to [@Sumit-Ridhal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7331574/sumit-ridhal) i found out that my store module was wrong so I had to change it and now I don't know how to access its state.

Thnx in advance,
Cheers

Comment: Access from where? can you share the code of the component you are trying to access the store?

Comment: @GerardoRosciano i just updated my question and added an Vue file for reference.

Comment: in the view you should be able to access it through categories.categories. what happens when you check that var? code seems ok. Try to install this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=es it will help you debug

Comment: @GerardoRosciano I am getting an empty object if I try to access the categories module. Until few hours ago i used to const state { categories: }... and at that time, i could have accessed categories.categories but not now... I can't get my head around this :(

Comment: Should be working, do me a favor, try to create a fiddle or something, it would be faster for us to help you. also, install the devtools, there you can inspect the variables

Answer (score 0):

store.state." module name"."state data

I do store modules like this .

this is index store. stores/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import posts from '@/store/posts' // import external store mod
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    posts
  },
  strict: true,
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState()
  ],
  state: {...... etc
```

posts store module

```
  // how to access this store console.log('module state', store.state.posts.data)
    export default {
      state: {
        data: 'dfsd'
      },
      getters: {
      },
      mutations: {
      },
      actions: {
      }
    }
```

get store module data

import store from '@/store/'

store.state.posts.data